# How to dynamically bind the value of a checkbox Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Hi all: I have a component. The component view has a table:

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Recipients List</h2>
<br>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Select</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="#rp of arrAll">   
            <td>{{rp.id}}</td>             
            <td>{{rp.name}}</td>
            <td>{{rp.phone}}</td>                
            <td>{{rp.isActivated?'Active':'Inactive'}}</td>             
            <td>
                <input #{{rp.id}}  type="checkbox" (change)="checkbox(value)">
            </td>
        </tr>          
    </tbody>
</table>

<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="newRecipient()">New Recipient</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" (click) ="deleteRecipients()">Delete Recipients</button>
```

Here is a link to an image of the [table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLGe9.png) which was generated using *ngFor.

The business logic is "When the delete button is clicked all the checked recipients must be deleted". I want to pass a parameter to my delete function (which I think should be an array containing the checked recipient ids)

Here is my component code:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
import { Router, RouteParams } from 'angular2/router';
import {RecipientsService}    from'../../services/recipients/recipients.service';
import {Recipient} from '../../models/recipient/recipient';

@Component({
selector: 'recipient-list-view',
templateUrl: './app/components/recipient-list-view/recipient-list-view.html',
styleUrls: ["./app/components/recipient-list-view/style.css"]
})

export class RecipientListViewComponent {

arrAll: Recipient[];

constructor(private recipientsService: RecipientsService, params:    RouteParams, private router: Router) {
    this.arrAll = recipientsService.getAll();        
}

newRecipient() {
    this.router.navigate(['../NewRecipient']);
}

deleteRecipients() {  //need to know which recipients are checked

    console.log("delete");
}


}
```

I would like to know how to achieve this.

Cheers

Comment: <input #{{rp.id}}  type="checkbox" (change)="checkbox(value)">   #{{rp.id}} is this grammatical

Answer (score 11):

Add a property `selected` to your recipient. On the checkbox change, put it as true.

Once the user clicks delete all recipients, just filter the list for the ones who are selected.

Something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Recipients List</h2>
    <br>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Select</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="#rp of arrAll">   
                <td>{{rp.id}}</td>             
                <td>{{rp.name}}</td>
                <td>{{rp.phone}}</td>                
                <td>{{rp.isActivated?'Active':'Inactive'}}</td>             
                <td>
                    <input #{{rp.id}}  [(ngModel)]="rp.selected" type="checkbox" (change)="checkbox(rp)">
                </td>
            </tr>          
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="newRecipient()">New Recipient</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" (click) ="deleteRecipients()">Delete Recipients</button>
</div>
```

And the component:

```
export class RecipientListViewComponent {

     arrAll: Recipient[];

     constructor(private recipientsService: RecipientsService, params: RouteParams, private router: Router) {
        this.arrAll = recipientsService.getAll();        
    }

    newRecipient() {
        this.router.navigate(['../NewRecipient']);
    }

    deleteRecipients() {  //need to know which recipients are checked
        let selected = this.arrAll.filter((x) => x.selected)
        console.log(selected);
    }

    checkbox(recipient) {
        recipient.selected = (recipient.selected) ? false : true;
    }
}
```

Comment: for simplicity sake: recipient.selected = !receipient.selected;

Answer (score 2):

If you can add one more property to your "Recipient" model, then is very much easy to track the selected records.

Added a "selected" property in your Recipient model and two way bind the checkbox to selected property.

```
<input #{{rp.id}}  type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="rp.selected">
```

Now add a method in the component to get all selected records

```
private getSelected() {
    return this.arrAll.filter((item) => item.selected);
}
```

Then get the selected records

```
deleteRecipients() {  
    console.log(this.getSelected());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a function in your controller that would be triggered when checking the checkbox (ng-click of checkbox). Depending on the value of the checkbox, you'll know if it's being checked/unchecked. Maintain another model for the list of checked recipients. Append the recipient to the list if checked, delete if unchecked. When calling delete just delete ones in that model?