# How to separate model value from select value in an option?

Tags: angular, data-binding

I want to select a value in a dropdown list made of years from 2015 to the current year:

```
<select (change)="changeDate()">
      <option  *ngFor="let exercice of exercices" (ngModel)="selectedExercise" 
      [value]="exercice">{{exercice}}</option>
</select>
```

I have in my model the variable "selectedExercise : number", and I want it to dynamically take the value of my select.
I found this post : [How to dynamically bind the value of a checkbox Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056815/how-to-dynamically-bind-value-in-checkbox-angular-2)
Interesting, but I don't understand the "#" elements.
Does anyone have a solution and eventually a better documentation about these "#" than : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngModel ?

Thank you for reading

Comment: `ngModel` should be on the `<select>` not on the `<option>`. On the `<option>` element use `[value]="..."` for string values and `[ngValue]="..."` for object values.

Comment: These `#` are about different Forms. You are using a Template Driven Form, and therefore you don't need that.

Comment: Here's a simple example: https://plnkr.co/edit/EfFqXSWbash2jOSxu8vE?p=preview